# How to prevent scroll when a-tag is clicked on carousel of Vue.js

Tags: html, css, vue.js

How to prevent scroll when a-tag is clicked on carousel of Vue.js

I composed some sort of carousel card to imitate the ones we can see on Netflix's main page.
It works okay on a single component. But when I added multiple carousel components to a vue, whenever I click an arrow on any carousel, the page scrolls to place the carousel on top of the screen. Furthermore, once it's scrolled, the arrow doesn't work unless I manually scroll the page first. I've tried several solutions I could find on stackoverflow, but none of them seem to work—mostly leading the carousel to stop rolling.
This is a single section of a carousel. I believe  is causing the issue.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: Arial;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.wrapper section {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.wrapper section .item3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 2px;
  transition: 250ms all;
}

.wrapper section img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper section .item3:hover {
  margin: 0 40px;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.wrapper section .item3 .heading {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: var(--font-size-md)
}

.wrapper section .item3 .heading:hover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.300);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: var(--font-size-md)
}

.wrapper section img:hover~.heading {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.300);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: var(--font-size-md)
}


/* .wrapper section .item3 .duration {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20px;
    color: #fff;
  } */

.wrapper section .arrow__btn {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 6em;
  background: black;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper section .left-arrow {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.wrapper section .left-arrow:hover {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, black 100%);
}

.wrapper section .right-arrow {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.wrapper section .right-arrow:hover {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, black 100%);
}
```

```html
<section id="section7" class="section7">
  <a href="#section9" class="arrow__btn left-arrow">‹</a>
  <div class="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#movieModal" @click="getMovie(movies[0].id)">
    <div class="item3">
      <img :src="`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movies[0]?.poster_path}`" alt="Describe Image">
      <h5 class="heading">{{ movies[0]?.title }}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#movieModal" @click="getMovie(movies[1].id)">
    <div class="item3">
      <img :src="`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movies[1]?.poster_path}`" alt="Describe Image">
      <h5 class="heading">{{ movies[1]?.title }}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#movieModal" @click="getMovie(movies[2].id)">
    <div class="item3">
      <img :src="`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movies[2]?.poster_path}`" alt="Describe Image">
      <h5 class="heading">{{ movies[2]?.title }}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#movieModal" @click="getMovie(movies[3].id)">
    <div class="item3">
      <img :src="`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movies[3]?.poster_path}`" alt="Describe Image">
      <h5 class="heading">{{ movies[3]?.title }}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#movieModal" @click="getMovie(movies[4].id)">
    <div class="item3">
      <img :src="`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movies[4]?.poster_path}`" alt="Describe Image">
      <h5 class="heading">{{ movies[4]?.title }}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#section8" class="arrow__btn right-arrow">›</a>
</section>
```

Is there any way I can make it work?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("a").addEventListener("click",function(){e.preventDefault()});

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know what kind of scripts you are using to make this work, I feel like you are using bootstrap, if that is correct, I would first recommend moving this to bootstrap vue rather than this. Nevertheless, I hope this helps if you don't feel like switching.

You are using an anchor tag and passing it an id like this

```
<a href="#my-div">content</a>
```

In browsers, this usually scrolls you to the div that has the ID. I would recommend adding preventDefault() to all click events on these anchor tags, you can either do this by adding a click function to all anchor tags using vue like this

```
<a href="#my-div" @click.prevent>content</a> // this automatically prevents click event
// or 
<a href="#my-div" @click="myFunction">content</a>
// or in case you want vue to automatically remove click events but add custom functions
<a href="#my-div" @click.prevent="otherFunction">content</a> // this automatically prevents click event



<script>
export default {
...other stuff
methods: {
myFunction(e) {
e.preventDefault();
}
}
}
</script>
```

though not preferred you may try to prevent this events manually without going through  vue, this can be done in the mounted hook
again I would not recommend using this and sticking to vue's own @click event handler

```
<script>
export default {
...,
mounted() {
const parent = document.getElementById("id-of-parent-div-that-has-all-anchor-tags") //this is done so you don't mess up anchor tags outside this div
parent.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((anchor) => {
anchor.onclick= (e) => e.preventDefault();
})

}

}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explaination. But I am afraid I have tried those already and I just tried again.. It only makes the arrow button doesn't work at all. The arrow button with a-tag is supposed to circle the carousel by switching it to the previous/next section

Comment: No worries, are you using VueBootstrap's carousel or vanilla javascript's version of bootstrap, I imagine mixing them both wouldn't work out very well, if you're not using BootstrapVue, you might wanna consider switching libraries
Is it possible for you to create a codepen of the code where you replicate the problem so other's can take look?